# Is class or method definition also an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading a Ruby book and it looks like even a method or class definition is an object.
So, I can do this:

```
my_class = class Abc; end
```

my_class evaluates to NilClass.

There's not much you can do with this variable. But still what's the point of having a class or method definition to be a `nil` object?

Answer (score 3):

No, class definitions and method definitions are syntax, they aren't objects. They *do*, however *evaluate* to an object:

Method definitions evaluate to a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method:

```
def foo; end
#=> :foo
```

This allows you to do things like this, for example:

```
private def foo; end
```

Class definitions evaluate to the value of the last expression evaluated inside the definition:

```
class Foo; 'Hello' end
#=> 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally variables aren't assigned to classes or method definitions.

However, it is possible with anonymous classes:

```
MyClass = Class.new do
  # class body goes here
end
```

Method definitions return the symbol of the method name, which can be used to call the method in various ways

```
foo_symbol = def foo; "ok"; end
puts foo_symbol == :foo # => true

# call the method using send
send(foo_symbol) # => "ok"

# convert to a proc and call
method(foo_symbol).call # => "ok"
```

Of course the method is still callable by `foo`. If the goal was to make an anonymous method that was just assigned to the variable, then it'd be best to just make it a proc in the first place.

```
foo_proc = Proc.new { "ok" }
# it can be assigned as an instance method on the class
MyClass.send(:define_method, :foo, &foo_proc)
MyClass.new.foo # => "ok"
```

Though truth be told, this type of deconstruction isn't necessarily beneficial from a comprehensibility perspective and unless there's some metaprogramming going on it's probably simpler to use regular methods/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to think that the author meant that you can assign classes and methods to variables (rather than the literal statements that define them).

When you define a class, the block of code in which you define it will return the last evaluated statement. For instance, your example returns nil because nothing was evaluated.  But look at what happens when we add code to the class definition:

```
irb(main):026:0> class Abc
irb(main):027:1>   SOME_CONSTANT = 'boiled_frogs'
irb(main):028:1> end
=> "boiled_frogs"
```

If you wanted to assign the class to a variable, you would define the class first:

```
irb(main):040:0> class Abc ; end
=> nil
irb(main):041:0> the_class = Abc
=> Abc
```

Methods work a bit differently - a method *will* be returned (well, a symbol representing the method name) when you initially define it:

```
irb(main):037:0> def my_method
irb(main):038:1>   return 'boiled_frogs'
irb(main):039:1> end
=> :my_method
```